# Constant Rate of Decline Over x Period- Average Per Day

Tags: constants

Forgive me ignorance  in advance for this question as I'm not a mathematician in any respect. I can't even pretend to give correct terminology so I'll just give an example:

We're a a retail company. We buy 1000 units of products. We sell an equal amount of these products each day and by day 90 we have 0 products. **How do I calculate how many units we have on average each day over that 90 days?** (even better would be calculating the average units on hand in month 1, month 2, and month 3.

I can calculate this manually but I'm sure there must be a nice formula for this (I'll be putting the formula ultimately into Excel if that makes a difference)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Since the rate of change is **constant**, in $90$ days you sell $1000$ units, in $1$ day you sell $\frac{1000}{90} = \frac{100}{9}$ or $11.111 \cdots$ units.

As an extension, you can make a formula to find how many units you have in a given day, or how many days it would take to reach a given unit.

Let $y$ be the number of units, and $x$ be the number of days. The equation of a line is $y = mx+b$. Then the constant rate of change – the **slope** $m$ is $\frac{100}{9}$ as in the first part.

We now have $y = \frac{100}{9}x + b$. Since we know that in $90$ days, there will be $0$ units, we can substitute $x = 90$, $y = 0$ into the equation to get $0 = \frac{100}{9} \cdot 90 + b$. This is $0 = 1000+b$, so $b = 1000$. Putting it all together, we have $y = \frac{100}{9}x + 1000$. Now you can substitute $x = 30, 60, 90$ to find how how many units you have at the end of each month.